# Error Message Popup use in Batch program

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

This will be implemented into Choose your own adventure games and an option to "save" the game progress. I am trying to use the VBScript error popup in my batch files, how can I use the output of the yes, no, or ok button click in the batch file and have it goto option A if yes clicked or goto option B if no clicked?

VBScript popup:

```vb
x = MsgBox("INVALID INPUT", 1+32, "WARNING")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the return code from the `MsgBox` as the exit code for the VBScript:

```vb
x = MsgBox(...)
WScript.Quit x
```

Then evaluate the VBScript exit code in your batch script:

```cmd
wscript.exe //NoLogo C:\path\to\your.vbs
if %errorlevel% equ 7 (
    rem User clicked "yes".
) else if %errorlevel% equ 6 (
    rem User clicked "no".
) else (
    rem User cancelled or something unexpected happened.
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This helped in a huge way